# URL is appending forward slash '/' before query string

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-5, routes

I'm facing a strange issue , when I try to hit url like

```
www.mywebsite.com/walkthrough?hostid=12345
```

It is automatically appending '/' before'?' in the url.
like

```
www.mywebsite.com/walkthrough/?hostid=12345
```

and hence I'm not able to get parameter hostid.

**routes**

```
 Route::get('/walkthrough', ['uses' => 'WalkthroughController@index']);
```

**HTACCESS**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
#php_value allow_url_fopen 0
#php_value allow_url_include 0
</IfModule>
```

why this is happening ? Any help is much much appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code an routes?

Comment: Added routes ..please check the question.

Comment: And if you add another route with `Route::get('/walkthrough/{step}', ['uses' => 'WalkthroughController@index2'])`, there you can get the `hostid` `public function index2($hostid) {}`

Comment: That's odd. Try defining route as mentioned in my answer below.

Comment: The requirement of the project is that the url should be used in the way I shown above in the question www.mywebsite.com/walkthrough?hostid=12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a .htaccess issue. Though I am surprised you can't still pluck out the url parameter, as it should make little difference if the `/` is there or not.

A typical laravel htaccess file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

Based on a discussion in the comments, it seems that a conflicting directory in the `public` directory called `walkthrough` was/is causing the trouble.

Laravel will only trim off the trailing `/` if there isn't a matching directory (rightly so).

There is no harm having the trailing `/` though.

Comment: I checked it, its not working. :(
Issue is that its not accepting    /walkthrough in url. Measn its adding /? after walkthrough keyword only.

Comment: issue is with that specific keyword :(

Comment: Is your htaccess working? This is most likely unrelated to laravel

Comment: Yes its working. Only issue with /walkthrough in url.

Comment: Can you update your question with a) your .htaccess and b) an example of a route that is working

Comment: edited..please check..example of route that is working is   Route::get('/about', ['uses' => 'LoginController@about']);

Comment: Cool. One more (crazy) question - do you have a folder inside the public directory called "walkthrough" ?

Comment: :) I would say that would be it. I will update my answer

Comment: Great..Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the route like this as mentioned in laravel documentation.

```
Route::get('walkthrough', 'WalkthroughController@index');
```

Refer [basic routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing)